# iOS Image Carousel for IPad app

Tags: image, ios

I'm trying to figure out how to display several images in an iPad app.  I would like to display them like the IPod album art carousel.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try OpenFlow.. My Internet connection is awful tonight or else I'd look up the URL. In fact I'll send this and then try..

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a general-purpose carousel library for this:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

You can configure it for various display types including 'classic' CoverFlow, or easily implement a bespoke layout style.

Comment: I reviewed your library.. Its simply awesome. Hats off to your efforts man. I recommend this over open flow..!